# Is there a way to set all existing ReactJS states without specifying them?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have component which is used multiple times in same page and for each time it is being displayed there is set new state for it. State names come from DB so I don't know state names. I'm wondering if there is way to set all existing states to *false*. In each component there is checkbox. In my page there should be selected only one checkbox at once. By changing all states to *false* i could uncheck all checkboxes when other is clicked.

```
onSelect = (e) => {
 this.setState({
  // allStates: false,  <------------- Something like that 
  [e.target.getAttribute('data-id')]: !this.state[e.target.getAttribute('data-id')]
 });
}


render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <SearchResult data-id="a" pName="Duracell 1" onClick={this.onSelect} selected={this.state.a} />
    <SearchResult data-id="b" pName="Duracell 2" onClick={this.onSelect} selected={this.state.b} />
    <SearchResult data-id="c" pName="Duracell 3" onClick={this.onSelect} selected={this.state.c} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

So before setting state to *true* I need somehow set all other states to *false*.

Comment: You may want to take a look at redux : https://redux.js.org/

Comment: I believe that there must be simpler way to do that then use Redux. I mean less code + I don't need to make those states global, they are staying within 1 component. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Why don't you use `<input type="radio" ... />`?

Comment: Yes, true, maybe i could just use map() function with input type=radio. I think I just forgot about this option. I am just very into trying to use React possibilities to get used to it quicker. If current option will not work out will do this then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelect = (e) => {
  const currentDataId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');

  this.setState(state => {
    const newState = {};
    for (const dataId in state) {
      newState[dataId] = dataId === currentDataId; // false for everything but current
    }

    return newState;
  });
}
```

Notice that since asynchronous state updater function should be used to process current state, synthetic event should be processed beforehand.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but in browser react window there is no state set when I'm using this approach. Not sure why.

Comment: @EdgarsŠusts What do you mean? No setState method? Please, provide, a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I double checked. Before i mean that state is not set at all. But now i see that all states are set only to false. So i will just add line after your code which will set selected item state to true. Maybe for you it is working and I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm can't say what's wrong because the question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you're doing everything as described, I'd expect it to work. Did you debug currentDataId? I'm not very fond of storing data as data attribute, this smells like jQuery, a common way in React is to provide it as callback arg, `... onClick={() => this.onSelect(this.state.a)} selected={this.state.a}`. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem if it persists.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zu6jxb**

Basically if you "don't know" exact keys of the object, you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and reduce that array of keys to new object with all keys set to false, like:

```
const maleAllValuesFalse = object => Object
  .keys(object)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr]: false,
  }), {});
```

Here we set all values of an object to false.
Let's see how we can merge this solution into a React app.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  // you can use any other attribute
  // I just used name...
  const name = event.target.getAttribute('name');

  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const nextCheck = !prevState[name];

    return {
      ...(nextCheck ? maleAllValuesFalse(prevState) : {}),
      [name]: nextCheck,
    };
  });
};
```

I'm not a big fan of recreating such behaviour by using `<input type="checkbox" />` because this is how native `<input type="radio" />` works, without line of JavaScript: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/th0sbadm/).